# Jquery Load. Wait 500 ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code like this. There are two conditions for the content to load. Successful response and if image loaded (function waitFormages). How do I make a condition by type if 500ms has passed load? Without using setTimeout. setTimeout will simply delay the load. ie each time will pass 500 ms and then load.

```
/* ---- */
// item
$('.js_toggle-item').click(function() {     
    var url = $(this).attr('data-item-url');

    // ajax load
    $('.js_control-item').load('/i/' + url + ' #item_component', function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == 'success') {
            $('.it').waitForImages(function() {
                $('.js_page-backdrop').removeAttr('style');
                $('.js_control').attr('data-state', 'item');
                $('.js_control').attr('style', 'transform: translate3d(0, calc(80px), 0)');
            });
        }
    });
});
/* ---- END */
```

Comment: You can do using setTimeout I have a trick

Comment: If you say then I can post for you

Comment: Not thank you) setTimeout I can use myself.

Comment: i don't understand you mean you want to know if loading take more time than 500ms ?